# Spark driver memory exceeded the storage memory

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

[image]
I can not understand why in Spark UI, the driver used storage memory (2.1GB) exceeds the total available memory (1.5GB).
When I use the same application with Spark 2.1.1 I don't have the same behavior, the Spark driver memory is few Mb. Also, the application behavior becomes slower and slower with the same data.

My questions:

- The used storage memory is a accumulation and not the current used memory?
- Is a UI bug?
- What are these 2.1Gb of data?